# cURL SSL: verify & allow a site that uses another site's certificate

Tags: php, curl, openssl

Site A uses an SSL certificate from Site B. I want my PHP code to connect to Site A over HTTPS using cURL, and I'd like that to be as secure as possible. (Note: I can't get Site A or B to change their setups).

One way I've gotten this to kind of work is to visit Site A in a browser, save the cert to the server, and point to that cert using CURLOPT_CAINFO (and set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to true). However, in that case I have to set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST to 0 (because Site B's name is on the cert).

What I'd prefer to do is somehow tell cURL to allow the connection if and only if Site A is using Site B's cert (with Site B's name on it).

Is there a way to do that with PHP cURL or by changing a server setting? Or, is there some other PHP library that would let me do this as transparently as possible?

ADDED: this may or may not complicate matters, but I'm trying to load https://SomeSmallShoppingSiteIDontControl.com ("Site A"), which uses a cert valid only for SomeMajorShoppingSiteProviderIAlsoDontControl.com ("Site B").

Comment: Just so I understand, you're trying to fetch pages from `https://foo.example.com`, but that site uses the certificate from `https://bar.example.com`, which itself is entirely unrelated?